# I want to Reload page after iframe close bt it reloaded at time of loading?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I want to reload a page after iframe close .. how to do this ?? i cant understand ? please any one can help me in this code ?

```
 <div class="form-group border-none">
  <div class="col-md-12 ">
 <iframe src="<?php echo $this->base_url; ?>Profile_pic/index/<?php echo $id;   ?>" width="100%" style="border:none; height:52px;">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
             </div>           

       <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () 
            {
               if (! localStorage.justOnce) 
               {
                localStorage.setItem("justOnce", "true");
                window.location.reload();
                }
            }

        </script>
```

Comment: How does one close an iframe?

Comment: I used close button image

Comment: Then u should apply websky answer on your button click event and it will work

Answer (score 2):

if you reload with iframe and iframe is popup, use:

```
parent.window.location.reload();
```

iframe is in parent.window

if iframe not popup use:

```
parent.document.location.reload();
```

Comment: i want to reload only once ??

Comment: Then u also set the corresponding `parent.window.localStorage.setItem("justOnce", "true");` code in there :)